# Creating MBed Library, Error "expected an identifier"

Tags: c++, c, mbed

Here is my code. When I try to compile it there is an error "expected an identifier" I believe it is to do with how I formatted the Timer2 initiation.

What do I need to alter to allow this code to compile?

Many thanks.

I can add the header file if needed.

```
#include "Timer2.h"
#include "LPC17xx.h"


unsigned int _presc;

Timer2::Timer2(unsigned long pres, ClockType cs) :
{
    power(1);
    prescale(pres);
    selectClock(cs);
}

Timer2::~Timer2()
{
    power(0);
}

void Timer2::prescale(unsigned int p)
{
    _presc = p-1;
    LPC_TIM2->PR = _presc;
}

unsigned long Timer2::getPrescale()
{
    return _presc;
}

void Timer2::capture0(ChangeType change, bool interrupt)
{
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<8); //setup CAP2:0 on pin P0.4 DIP 30
    if ( change == rising) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1;
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x0<<1;
    } else if ( change == falling) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x0;
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<1;
    } else if( change == changing) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1;
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<1;
    }
    if (interrupt == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<2;
    }
}

void Timer2::capture1(ChangeType change, bool interrupt)
{
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<10); //setup CAP2:1 on pin P0.5 DIP 29
    if ( change == rising) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<3;
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x0<<4;
    } else if ( change == falling) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x0<<3;
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<4;
    } else if( change == changing) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<3;
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<4;
    }
    if (interrupt == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->CCR |= 0x1<<5;
    }
}

void Timer2::capture0Stop()
{
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<8); //stop CAP2:0
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<7);
}

void Timer2::capture1Stop()
{
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<10); //stop CAP2:1
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<9);
}

unsigned long Timer2::time_us()
{
    return _presc * LPC_TIM2->TC /96.0;
}

void Timer2::start()
{
    LPC_TIM2->TCR |= 0x0<<1;
    LPC_TIM2->TCR |= 0x1<<0;
}

void Timer2::stop()
{
    LPC_TIM2->TCR |= 0x0<<1;
    LPC_TIM2->TCR |= 0x0<<0;
}

void Timer2::reset()
{
    LPC_TIM2->TCR |= 0x1<<1;
}

void Timer2::match0(unsigned long value, bool stop, bool interrupt, bool reset, MatchAction action = nothing)
{
    if (action == nothing) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<12);   //Select pin p0.6 (p8)
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<11);   //Select pin p0.6 (p8)
    } else if (action == set0) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<12);   //Select pin p0.6 (p8)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x2<<5;            //Set pin low
    } else if (action == set1) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<12);   //Select pin p0.6 (p8)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x1<<5;            //Set pin high
    } else if (action == toggle) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<12);   //Select pin p0.6 (p8)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x3<<5;            //Toggle pin
    }
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<12);   //Select pin p0.6 (p8)
    LPC_TIM2->MR0 = value;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<0;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<1;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<2;
    if (interrupt == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<0;
    }
    if (reset == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<1;
    }
    if (stop == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<2;
    }

}

void Timer2::match1(unsigned long value, bool stop, bool interrupt, bool reset, MatchAction action = nothing)
{
    if (action == nothing) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<14);   //Select pin p0.7 (p7)
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<13);   //Select pin p0.7 (p7)
    } else if (action == set0) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<14);   //Select pin p0.7 (p7)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x2<<7;            //Set pin low
    } else if (action == set1) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<14);   //Select pin p0.7 (p7)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x1<<7;            //Set pin high
    } else if (action == toggle) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<14);   //Select pin p0.7 (p7)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x3<<7;            //Toggle pin
    }
    LPC_TIM2->MR1 = value;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<3;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<4;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<5;
    if (interrupt == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<3;
    }
    if (reset == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<4;
    }
    if (stop == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<5;
    }
}

void Timer2::match2(unsigned long value, bool stop, bool interrupt, bool reset, MatchAction action = nothing)
{
    if (action == nothing) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<16);   //Select pin p0.8 (p6)
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<15);   //Select pin p0.8 (p6)
    } else if (action == set0) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<16);   //Select pin p0.8 (p6)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x2<<9;            //Set pin low
    } else if (action == set1) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<16);   //Select pin p0.8 (p6)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x1<<9;            //Set pin high
    } else if (action == toggle) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<16);   //Select pin p0.8 (p6)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x4<<9;            //Toggle pin
    }
    LPC_TIM2->MR2 = value;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<6;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<7;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<8;
    if (interrupt == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<6;
    }
    if (reset == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<7;
    }
    if (stop == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<8;
    }
}

void Timer2::match3(unsigned long value, bool stop, bool interrupt, bool reset, MatchAction action = nothing)
{
    if (action == nothing) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<18);   //Select pin p0.9 (p5)
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x0<<17);   //Select pin p0.9 (p5)
    } else if (action == set0) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<18);   //Select pin p0.9 (p5)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x2<<11;            //Set pin low
    } else if (action == set1) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<18);   //Select pin p0.9 (p5)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x1<<11;            //Set pin high
    } else if (action == toggle) {
        LPC_PINCON->PINSEL0 |= (0x3<<18);   //Select pin p0.9 (p5)
        LPC_TIM2->EMR |= 0x3<<11;            //Toggle pin
    }
    LPC_TIM2->MR3 = value;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<9;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<10;
    LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x0<<11;
    if (interrupt == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<9;
    }
    if (reset == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<10;
    }
    if (stop == true) {
        LPC_TIM2->MCR |= 0x1<<11;
    }
}

void Timer2::clockReset(unsigned long time, PinName match = p5)
{
    unsigned long t = time * 96.0;
    if (match == p5) {
        match3(t,0,1,1);
    } else if (match == p6) {
        match2(t,0,1,1);
    } else if (match == p7) {
        match1(t,0,1,1);
    } else if (match == p8) {
        match0(t,0,1,1);
    }
}

void Timer2::selectClock(ClockType clock)
{
    if (clock == Clock) {
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x1<<12; //PCLK_peripheral set to Clock
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x0<<13;
    } else if (clock == HalfClock) {
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x0<<12; //PCLK_peripheral set to Clock/2
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x1<<13;
    } else if (clock == QuarterClock) {
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x0<<12; //PCLK_peripheral set to Clock/4
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x0<<13;
    } else if (clock == EighthClock) {
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x1<<12; //PCLK_peripheral set to Clock/8
        LPC_SC->PCLKSEL1 |=0x1<<13;
    }
}

void Timer2::power(bool on)
{
    if (on == true) {
        LPC_SC->PCONP |=0x1<22; //timer2 power on
    } else {
        LPC_SC->PCONP |=0x0<22; //timer2 power off}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Timer2 constructor has a rogue `:`, which is used when you have initialization lists (i.e. when calling a base class constructor, or when setting values of class members). Since there are no identifiers in the list, you get the error. Remove the colon and it should work.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. It is compiling now. Thanks